# Nonresolved signal has multiple sources whereas i drive it once (VHDL)

Tags: signals, vhdl, modelsim

i have a problem with my VHDL code.
i am getting an error

> "Nonresolved signal 'temp' has multiple sources." .

I tried different things :
first, i had this :

```
adc_integer_expected  <= integer(volt_db(index)(lane) / (ADC_VOLT_MAX/4096.0));
```

But it causes an error saying me that "adc_integer_expected " has multiple sources. So I decided to cut it in 2 pieces like this :

```
temp <= (volt_db(index)(lane)) / (ADC_VOLT_MAX/4096.0);
adc_integer_expected  <= integer(temp);
```

But now i'm having 2 signals that have multiple sources : 'temp' and 'adc_integer_expected'

Thank you for your help.

Here is the code :

```
library IEEE, modelsim_lib;
use IEEE.Std_Logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use modelsim_lib.util.all;

library work;
use work.pkg_tool_box.all;
use work.bench_package.all;
use work.func_package.all;

use std.textio.all; 
use std.env.all;

architecture sc_0010 of SC_WRAPPER  is

  --Constants
  constant INCR_TH      : integer range 0 to 4095:=  1;
  signal   INCR_VOLT    : real    := 0.1;
  constant ADC_VOLT_MAX : real    := 3.0;       -- Reference
  signal   lane_incr    : integer := 0;

  --signal cnt : integer range 0 to ;
  signal spy_thresholds     : t_th_x;
  signal spy_voltages       : t_voltage_in;
  signal spy_adc_cntr       : t_adc_mes;
  signal spy_voltage_adc    : t_adc_in;
  signal spy_th_comp_rslt   : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
  signal spy_ir_spi         : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal spy_mux_addr       : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  signal spy_en_mux         : std_logic;
  --signal spy_adc_miso       : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  --signal spy_adc_model_out  : 


  signal th_db              : t_th_x;

  signal cnt_clk            : integer := 0;

  signal obz                : integer := 0;
  signal irl                : integer := 0;
  signal irh                : integer := 0;
  signal th_comp_rslt       : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');

  --Voltages    
  signal volt_db            : t_voltage_in;
  signal voltage_i          : real := 0.0;
  signal th_i               : integer range 0 to 4095 := 0;
  signal temp               : real := 0.0;

  --MUX MODEL
  signal volt_mux           : t_adc_in := (others => 0.0);                         -- output coming from the 
  --signal addr_mux

  --SPI
  --signal data_to_send       : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal sc_ir_spi          : std_logic;
  signal bit_cnt            : integer range 0 to 16;
  signal ir_spi_reg         : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal ir_signal          : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

  --ADC MODEL
  --signal adc_model_out      : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
  --signal Dout               : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
  --signal adc_integer_expected      : integer; 
  signal adc_mosi_sample         : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
  --signal mux_addr_sc         : std_logic_vector( 2 downto 0);
  --signal adc_cntrl_out      : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);

  signal adc_integer_expected        : integer := 0;
  signal adc_value_expected          : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  

  signal cnt_volt           : integer := 0;

  begin

  init_signal_spy("/testbench/inst_DUT/p_thresholds"               , "/testbench/inst_scenario/spy_thresholds"  , 0,-1);
  init_signal_spy("/testbench/channel_voltage"                     , "/testbench/inst_scenario/spy_voltages"    , 0,-1);
  init_signal_spy("/testbench/inst_DUT/adc_chX_data"               , "/testbench/inst_scenario/spy_adc_cntr"    , 0,-1);
  --init_signal_spy("/TESTBENCH/g_inst_MUX_MODEL/tb_adc_ainp_chx"  , "/testbench/inst_scenario/spy_adc_cntr"    , 0,-1);
  --init_signal_spy("/testbench/tb_adc_miso_chx"                     , "/testbench/inst_scenario/spy_voltage_adc" , 0,-1);
  init_signal_spy("/testbench/inst_DUT/comp_th_rslt"               , "/testbench/inst_scenario/spy_th_comp_rslt", 0,-1);
  init_signal_spy("/testbench/tb_adc_ainp_chx"                     , "/testbench/inst_scenario/spy_voltage_adc", 0,-1);
  init_signal_spy("/testbench/inst_DUT/spi_th_reg"                 , "/testbench/inst_scenario/spy_ir_spi", 0,-1);
  --init_signal_spy("/TESTBENCH/g_ins_ADC/tb_adc_miso_chx"         , "/testbench/inst_scenario/spy_adc_miso"    , 0,-1);
  --init_signal_spy("/testbench/inst_DUT/MUX_ADDR"                    , "/testbench/inst_scenario/spy_mux_addr", 0,-1);
  --init_signal_spy("/testbench/inst_DUT/inst_th_comparator/cnt_lane","/testbench/inst_th_comparator/spy_lane"  , 0,-1);  

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --                                                     Process     : allocation
  --                                                     Description : Values allocation to the thresholds and the voltages
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  allocation : process
  begin
  
  --HW_RST_N         <= '0'; 
  --SW_RST_N         <= '0'; 
  --SEL_RSM          <= '0'; 
  --PWR_ON           <= '0';
  --CH_HERE            <= (others => '1');
  --A_MUX              <= (others => '0');
  --EN_MUX             <= (others => '0');
  CH_HERE(0) <= '1';
  CH_HERE(1) <= '1'; --'0' after 500 ns, '1' after 3 us, '0' after 8 us;
  CH_HERE(2) <= '1'; --'1' after 500 ns, '0' after 4 us, '1' after 9 us;

  STST_N             <= '1';
  obz                <= 1000;
  irl                <= 2000;
  irh                <= 3000;
  th_db              <= (others => (others => ( (std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(obz,12))), (std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(irl,12))), (std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(irh,12))) )));
  volt_db            <= (others => (others => 0.0));
  --mux_addr_sc        <= "010"; -- MUX = 2 at the beginning
  --adc_sample         <= '0';

  --FORCE_EN            <= (others => '0'); 
  xprint("","    *******************************************    ");
  xprint("","           SCENARIO 1 : Test ...                   ");
  xprint("","    *******************************************    ");

    UVLO_N  <= '0';          
    wait for 100 ns;       
    UVLO_N  <= '1';
    wait for 0 ns;

    --signal_force("/testbench/inst_DUT/ir_rslt", "0000", 0 ns, freeze, -1 ns, 0);


    --for th_i in 0 to 4096/INCR_TH loop
      for lane in 0 to 7 loop
        for channel in 0 to 3 loop
          for threshold in 0 to 2 loop
            th_db(channel)(lane)(0) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned((1000 + lane_incr), 12));
            th_db(channel)(lane)(1) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned((2000 + lane_incr), 12));
            th_db(channel)(lane)(2) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned((3000 + lane_incr), 12));
            lane_incr <= lane_incr + 1;
            --th_db(channel)(lane)(threshold) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(increment((to_integer(unsigned(th_db(channel)(lane)(threshold)))), 4096,INCR_TH), 12));
            wait for 0 ns;
            xprint("->", "th_db("&ToS(channel)&")("&ToS(lane)&")("&ToS(threshold)&") vaut : " &ToS(th_db(channel)(lane)(threshold)));
            signal_force("/testbench/inst_DUT/p_thresholds("&ToS(channel)&")("&ToS(lane)&")("&ToS(threshold)&")", ToS(th_db(channel)(lane)(threshold)), 0 ns , freeze , -1 ns , 0);
          end loop;
        end loop;
      end loop;
      xprint("-->", "th_db finito");
    --end loop;


      -- Another process ???
      for volt_i in 0 to integer(ADC_VOLT_MAX/INCR_VOLT) loop       -- 3.0/0.1
        for lane in 0 to 7 loop
          for channel in 0 to 3 loop
            --volt_db(channel)(lane) <= increment(volt_db(channel)(lane),ADC_VOLT_MAX,INCR_VOLT);
            if(volt_db(channel)(lane) < ADC_VOLT_MAX - INCR_VOLT) then
              volt_db(channel)(lane) <= volt_db(channel)(lane) + INCR_VOLT;
              INCR_VOLT <= INCR_VOLT + 0.1;
            else
               volt_db(channel)(lane) <= volt_db(channel)(lane) + INCR_VOLT - ADC_VOLT_MAX;
            end if;
            wait for 0 ns;
            signal_force("/testbench/channel_voltage("&ToS(channel)&")("&ToS(lane)&")", ToS(volt_db(channel)(lane)), 0 ns , freeze , -1 ns , 0);    --TESTBENCH
            xprint("->", "volt_db("&ToS(channel)&")("&ToS(lane)&") vaut : " &ToS(volt_db(channel)(lane)));
            --xprint("->", "spy_voltage("&ToS(channel)&")("&ToS(lane)&") vaut : " &ToS(spy_voltages(channel)(lane)));
          end loop;
        end loop;
        wait for 0 ns;

        --for lane in 0 to 7 loop
        --  for channel in 0 to 3 loop
        --    if(spy_voltages /= volt_db) then
        --      xprint("->", "Data error, the voltages of your ADC are different of what is expected. Try again !");
        --      xprint("->", "spy voltage("&ToS(channel)&")("&ToS(lane)&") vaut : " &ToS(spy_voltages(channel)(lane)));
        --      xprint("->", "volt_db("&ToS(channel)&")("&ToS(lane)&") vaut : " &ToS(volt_db(channel)(lane)));
        --    else
        --      xprint("-->", "Voltages spy OK");
        --    end if;
        --  end loop;
        --end loop;

        --wait until rising_edge(TICK);       
        
      end loop;      

    --wait for 1 us;
    --xprint("->", "STST_N assertion");
    --ST_ST_N <= '0';
    -- wait until ...



    --A_MUX  <= "001" after 62.5 ns, "010" after 938 ns, "011" after 1875 ns, "100" after 2813 ns, "101" after 3751 ns, "110" after 4689 ns, "111" after 5627 ns;
    --EN_MUX <= "1111";
    --wait for 1 us;
    --CH_HERE          <= (others => '1') after 60 ns;

    --wait for 50 ns;    
    --signal_force("/TESTBENCH/tb_en_mux" , "111111111", 0 ns , freeze , -1 ns , 0);
    
    --wait for 50 * T_Tick;          
    --signal_release("/TESTBENCH/tb_en_mux",0);

    --ok_ko()
    
    wait for 1 ms;   
      
    xprint("**","      END OF SIMULATION       ** "); 
    stop(2);
    
  end process allocation;

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --                                                            Process     : test
  --                                                            Description : Control and verification
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  -- voltage to adc_model_out
  -- adc_model_out to adc_ctrl_out (spy)
  -- adc_ctrl_out (spy) to th_comparatot_out (SPI)      
  g_inst_ADC_CTRL_test : for index in 0 to 3 generate               -- The four ADC are in parallel so --> generate
   
  test_verif : process           -- ADC_MODEL Sampling

  --variable adc_integer_expected        : integer := 0;
  --variable adc_value_expected          : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');

  --variable mux_addr_sc                 :  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);                             
  --variable adc_sample             : std_logic := '0';

  -- Data_sampling new name => expected en integer
  -- adc_model_out new name => 12 bit expected from voltage
  -- adc_model_miso new name => 12 bit sampled from adc_model
  begin
    --adc_integer_expected <= 0;
      for lane in 0 to 7 loop
        wait until(falling_edge(SPI_SS_N));
        wait for 62.5 ns;         -- wait for one clock pulse
          --for channel in 0 to 3 loop
        if(EN_MUX = '1') then
          volt_mux(index) <= volt_db(index)(to_integer(unsigned(MUX_ADDR)));
        else
          volt_mux(index) <= 0.0;
        end if;
        --CheckValue(volt_mux(index), spy_voltage_adc(index), "Comparison result for the output of the mux, for channel : "&CHANNEL_NAME(index));
          --end loop;
            ------------------------------------------- Check if the MUX value changes at the good time ---------------------------------------
        --wait for 62.5 ns;
        --mux_addr_sc <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integer(mux_addr_sc + 1),3));
        --CheckValue(MUX_ADDR, mux_addr_sc, "MUX VALUE IN THE SCENARIO is : "&mux_addr_sc &" and the value in the design is : "&MUX_ADDR);
            ------------------------------------------- Check the value coming from the ADC MODEL ---------------------------------------------
        if (EN_MUX = '1') then
          temp                  <= (volt_db(index)(lane)) / (ADC_VOLT_MAX/4096.0);
          adc_integer_expected  <= integer(temp);
          --adc_integer_expected  <= integer(volt_db(index)(lane) / (ADC_VOLT_MAX/4096.0));
          wait for 0 ns;
          adc_value_expected   <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(adc_integer_expected, 12));
          xprint("--", "ADC DATA channel "&CHANNEL_NAME(index)&" lane "&Tos(lane)&" expected value is : "&ToS(adc_integer_expected)&" (="&ToS(adc_value_expected)&")");
          
           ------------------------------------------- Check the value coming from the ADC CONTROLER and compare it with the ADC MODEL's value   ----------------
          for adc_bit in 0 to 14 loop
            wait until(rising_edge(ADC_SCK));
              if ((2 <= adc_bit) and (adc_bit < 14) ) then
                adc_mosi_sample(adc_bit - 2) <= ADC_MISO_CH(index);
              end if;
          end loop;
          wait for 10 ns;

          CheckValue(spy_adc_cntr(index),adc_value_expected, "ADC_MODEL output result for Channel : "&CHANNEL_NAME(index)&".");
          CheckValue(spy_adc_cntr(index),adc_mosi_sample,"ADC CTRL output result for channel : "&CHANNEL_NAME(index)&".");
          
        end if;
      end loop;
      --CheckValue(spy_adc_cntr(index), adc_value_expected, "Comparison result for Channel "&CHANNEL_NAME(index)&" ADC_CONTROLER output");

    end process test_verif;
  end generate g_inst_ADC_CTRL_test;

    spi_process : process
    begin

    wait until (SPI_SS_N = '1');
    wait for 10 ns;
    
    for lane in 0 to 7 loop
      for th in 0 to 11 loop
        case th is
          When 0  => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected >= th_db(0)(lane)(0));  -- irl_CHANNEL_A 
          When 1  => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected <= th_db(0)(lane)(1));  -- irh_CHANNEL_A
          When 2  => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected >= th_db(0)(lane)(2));  -- obz_CHANNEL_A
          When 3  => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected >= th_db(1)(lane)(0));  -- irl_CHANNEL_B
          When 4  => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected <= th_db(1)(lane)(1));  -- irh_CHANNEL_B
          When 5  => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected >= th_db(1)(lane)(2));  -- obz_CHANNEL_B
          When 6  => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected >= th_db(2)(lane)(0));  -- irl_CHANNEL_C
          When 7  => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected <= th_db(2)(lane)(1));  -- irh_CHANNEL_C
          When 8  => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected >= th_db(2)(lane)(2));  -- obz_CHANNEL_C
          When 9  => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected >= th_db(3)(lane)(0));  -- irl_CHANNEL_D
          When 10 => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected <= th_db(3)(lane)(1));  -- irh_CHANNEL_D
          When 11 => th_comp_rslt(th) <= bool_to_std(adc_value_expected >= th_db(3)(lane)(2));  -- obz_CHANNEL_D
          xprint("->", "th_comp_rslt("&ToS(th)&") vaut : " &ToS(th_comp_rslt(th)));
          --xprint("->", "th_db("&ToS(index)&")("&ToS(lane)&")("&ToS(th)&") vaut : " &ToS(th_db(index)(lane)(th)));
        end case;
        wait for 0 ns;
        --wait until rising_edge(MCLKIN);
        ir_signal(0) <= th_comp_rslt(0) and th_comp_rslt(1);
        ir_signal(1) <= th_comp_rslt(3) and th_comp_rslt(4);
        ir_signal(2) <= th_comp_rslt(6) and th_comp_rslt(7);
        ir_signal(3) <= th_comp_rslt(9) and th_comp_rslt(10);
        wait for 0 ns;
        --CheckValue(spy_th_comp_rslt, th_comp_rslt, "Comparison result for IR_SPI(16 bits) ");       --&CHANNEL_NAME(index)&Tos(lane)&" "&TH_NAME(th));
      end loop;
      
      ir_spi_reg <= ir_signal(3) & th_comp_rslt(11 downto 9) &
                    ir_signal(2) & th_comp_rslt( 8 downto 6) &
                    ir_signal(1) & th_comp_rslt( 5 downto 3) &
                    ir_signal(0) & th_comp_rslt( 2 downto 0);

      CheckValue(spy_ir_spi, ir_spi_reg, "IR result for lane number : " &ToS(lane));
    end loop;

    wait for 1 ms; 
    stop(2);

  end process spi_process;

  --end generate g_inst_ADC_CTRL_test;


  --output_latched : process
  --begin
--
  --end process;

end sc_0010;
```

Comment: You can't analyze a secondary unit prior to it's primary unit (the entity SC_WRAPPER is missing). This isn't a [mcve], lacking packages modelsim_lib.util, pkg_tool_box, bench_package, and func_package. That should tell you the code here is definitely not minimal (336 lines) and doesn't reproduce your error (message isn't complete either). It's also badly cluttered by commented out statements detracting readability by a non-author. Creating a minimal example would have lead you to answer Tricky presents. Most problems can be found doing so.

Comment: In -2008 (package std.env was introduced in -2008) compliant tools are not required to allow the use of packages analyzed in earlier revisions and package mti_util can't be analyzed into library modelsim_lib (15.10 Reserved words, "A reserved word shall not be used as an explicitly declared identifier", 5.2.2 Enumeration types, 5.2.2.1 "... Each enumeration literal is the declaration of the corresponding enumeration
literal. ..."), a portability issue. -2008 also provides methods useful in performing the equivalent of signal spying in a portable fashion.

Answer (score 4):

`Temp` is assigned inside a process which is itself inside a generate.  Hence you have 4 processes driving the signal temp. This is the same for `adc_value_expected`. You need to either remove these signals from these processes or make them an array like other signals in the process that use the generate iterator as the index.

Comment: Or declared them as block declarative items in the block declarative part of the generate statement (before the begin).